# Regular expression with re.search in python doesn't work

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to write a regular expression for a string `test = "ID=ss59537-RA:exon:0;Parent=ss59537-RA;"` and I so I had this `searchstr = re.compile(r'(ID = ss[\d]+-RA)(:)(exon:[\d]+)(;)(Parent = ss[\d]+-RA;)')` but when I tried to run the `re.search` command, I am not getting anything back. What am I doing wrong here?

```
searchstr = re.compile(r'(ID = ss[\d]+-RA)(:)(exon:[\d]+)(;)(Parent = ss[\d]+-RA;)')
test = "ID=ss59537-RA:exon:0;Parent=ss59537-RA;"
match = re.search(searchstr, test)
print(match)
```

I made sure the regular expression matches the string but when I ran it with `reg.search`, it doesn't work.

Comment: You have spaces around the equal signs in the regex

Comment: I think you wanted to use [the extended/verbose flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X) here. If you do that, [it works](https://regex101.com/r/kthsDK/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you planned to allow any number of spaces around the `=` signs. You may use `\s*` instead of literal spaces to match any 0 whitespace chars. I also advise removing `[` and `]` from around single atoms (`[\d]` = `\d`), and move the last `)` before the `;`:

```
import re
searchstr = re.compile(r'(ID\s*=\s*ss\d+-RA):(exon:\d+);(Parent\s*=\s*ss\d+-RA);')
test = "ID=ss59537-RA:exon:0;Parent=ss59537-RA;"
match = re.search(searchstr, test)
print(match.groups())
# => ('ID=ss59537-RA', 'exon:0', 'Parent=ss59537-RA')
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/WhaSBI).

Comment: Thanks for the useful suggestions as well for the Python demo tool. Seems like a good resource for testing as well as teaching..

Comment: @upendra And [here is another good regex testing tool](https://regex101.com/r/LsOM2V/1), with pattern explanation, debugging and code snippet generation features.